# missing terminator " character and undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("
              _____
             /     \
            / o   o \
            \   ^   /
             \_ ~ _/ \n");
    return 0;
}
```

I can't solve this errors, it's been five years I don't work with C and C++. I think itIs simple, but I can't solve.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: You cannot have string literals span multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put raw newline characters in C string literals.

You can put multiple string literals to be concatenated by the compiler:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("  _____\n"
            " /     \\\n"
            "/ o   o \\\n"
            "\\   ^   /\n"
            " \\_ ~ _/ \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that `\` is used for escape sequences, so you should write `\\` to use a character `\` in string literals.

Another way is putting `\` to the end of lines to have the compiler ignore the line end (concatenate lines):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("  _____\n\
 /     \\\n\
/ o   o \\\n\
\\   ^   /\n\
 \\_ ~ _/ \n");
    return 0;
}
```